# How SPSS calculates skewness

Tags: r, spss, skewness

All,

R provides information about how it calculates skewness (uses the formula provided by Kirk, 2008). My students are noticing that SPSS provides a different value, for which the formula is unclear. Does anyone know how SPSS calculates skewness and what that might be worse (or better?)?

Comment: See https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_there_any_difference_in_formula_when_calculating_Skewness_manually_and_using_SPSS_software  The authoritative reference can be found on the [SPSS technical manual pages](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27047033#en): link to the Statistics algorithms PDF, go to the "DESCRIPTIVES Algorithms" chapter, and look up the formula for "Skewness and Standard Error of Skewness." As far as `R` goes, the base software provides no skewness function, so exactly what `R` "information" are you referring to?

Comment: Thank you. The R 'Psych' package maps onto the formula given by Kirk (2008). I did not know we had an SPSS tech manual. Thanks!